# UnitTest on WebAPI controller with Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've an api with few methods in it. I need to authenticate user with `Windows Authentication` before it hits any of the controller methods. To achieve this, I've written a private method to get the `UserIdentity` and assign it to  a private `bool` variable.

Each of the controller methods will first check the bool to verify the user and if it fails, will throw `401` back to the front end.

Whilst writing unit test case to the controller methods, I'm not sure how to mock the `UserIdentity` or should I update the controller in a way to allow the testing of `UserIdentity`

Controller :

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
  private bool isUsrAuthenticated;

  public DefaultController()
  {
    AuthenticateUser();
  }

  private void AuthenticateUser()
  {
    isUsrAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
  {
    if (isUsrAuthenticated) { // do something }
    else { // throw 401 }
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public IHttpActionResult Update()
  {
    if (isUsrAuthenticated) { // do something }
    else { // throw 401 }
  }
}
```

The Unit Test results always return 401.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At run-time the `ApiController.User` property is set well after the constructor of the controller is invoked. That would mean that your current flow of calling it in the constructor like

```
public DefaultController() {
    AuthenticateUser();
}
```

is flawed and will not provide the expected behavior.

Lets fix the code first, then look at the unit test.

Use a property instead like

```
private bool IsUserAuthenticated {
    get {
        return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

and refactor the code accordingly

```
public class DefaultController : ApiController {

    private bool IsUserAuthenticated {
        get {
            return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProducts() {
        if (IsUserAuthenticated) { // do something }
        else { // throw 401 }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Update() {
        if (IsUserAuthenticated) { // do something }
        else { // throw 401 }
    }

    //...

}
```

Now, for testing the `ApiController`, the `User` property can be set while arranging the unit test in order for the test to be exercised as expected

For example

```
[TestMethod()]
public void DefaultController_Should_GetProducts() {
    //Arrange
    var username = "name_here";
    var userId = 2;

    var identity = new GenericIdentity(username, "");
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId.ToString()));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));

    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles: new string[] { });
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(principal);

    var controller = new DefaultController() {
        User = user //<-- Set the User on the controller directly
    };

    //Act
    var actionResult = controller.GetProducts();

    //Assert
    //...
}
```